# How do I display the data in my "lightning-datatable"?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, accordion

Here is my not the most ideal code, with which I got confused and can't output data to a table:

**//html**

```
<lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open>
                <div for:each={listDataForMonths} for:item="item" key={item.Id}>
                    <lightning-accordion-section label={item.date}>
                        <div style="height: 300px;">
                            <lightning-datatable
                                    key-field="Id"
                                    data={item}
                                    show-row-number-column
                                    row-number-offset={rowOffset}
                                    suppress-bottom-bar
                                    columns={columns}>
                            </lightning-datatable>
                        </div>
                    </lightning-accordion-section>
                </div>
</lightning-accordion>
```

**//js**

```
@track listDataForMonths;

rowOffset = 0;
columns = [
    { label: 'Description', fieldName: 'description', editable: true },
    { label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency', editable: true },
    { label: 'Action', type: 'button', typeAttributes: { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' } }
];

getRecordExpenseCardByYearAndMonth(){
    getRecordExpenseCardByYearAndMonth({year : this.selectedYear, month : this.selectedMonth, currentKeeper : this.currentContact.Id})
    .then((returnedData) => {
        if(returnedData != null){
            let listData = [];
            let checkForDate = [];
            returnedData.forEach((element) => {
                if(checkForDate.includes(element.CardDate__c)){
                    return;
                }
                let newExpenseCard = {date : element.CardDate__c};
                checkForDate.push(element.CardDate__c);
                let listDescriptions = [];
                let listAmounts = [];
                returnedData.forEach((item) => {
                    if(element.CardDate__c == item.CardDate__c){
                        listDescriptions.push(item.Description__c);
                        listAmounts.push(item.Amount__c);
                    }
                });
                newExpenseCard.description = listDescriptions;
                newExpenseCard.amount = listAmounts;
                listData.push(newExpenseCard);
            });
            this.listDataForMonths = listData;
        } else {
            console.log('Sometimes went wrong! returnedData: ' + returnedData);
        }
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Here is what the `listDataForMonths` contains after the js operation:

```
[{"date":"2021-06-20","description":["test1"],"amount":[30]},{"date":"2021-06-10","description":["test2","test3"],"amount":[10,10.5]}]
```

And this is what my accordion sections look like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your Column properties do not match the casing of your `listDataForMonths` properties.

Javascript is Case Sensitive. make sure that the casing matches.

Answer (score 1):

@unique user

Your JSON operation output:

`[{"date":"2021-06-20","description":["test1"],"amount":[30]},{"date":"2021-06-10","description":["test2","test3"],"amount":[10,10.5]}]`

In your output JSON above, description and amount has array of values instead of single value per row. Referring to the below example on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example

In order for your data-table to show the rows, your JSON should look something like below:

`[{"date":"2021-06-20","description": "test1","amount": "30"},{"date":"2021-06-10","description":"test2" ,"amount": "10"},{"date":"2021-06-10","description":"test3" ,"amount": "10.5"}]`

Let me know if the above information helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, the problem was related to my array, which I passed for display. I solved my problem late last night. This is what my array looks like now and it solves my problem: `[{"date":"2021-06-20","content":[{"Id":"a015e00000ItIdqAAF","description":"test1","amount":30}]},{"date":"2021-06-10","content":[{"Id":"a015e00000ItIiTAAV","description":"test2","amount":10},{"Id":"a015e00000IunUgAAJ","description":"test2","amount":10.5}]}]`